# Unable to handle the authenication dialog in firefox using selenlum webdriver

Tags: webdriver

When I try to launch any URL a proxy authentication dialog pops up for username and password. The code (java)  stops once the dialog appears and doesn't move further or throw an exception. 
How can i handle this?

Note: This is happening only with firefox(v 22.0). I am able to handle the authentication dialog in IE(v 7) using the Robot send keys.

Webdriver: selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0
Firefox version : 22.0
testNG version: 6.8.7

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are trying to reach HTTP authenticated page. The workaround is send username and password in url request like this:

```
driver.get("http://username:password@your-test-site.com");
```

where `driver` is assumed healthy living instance of `WebDriver`